# pthread_cond_wait returns after sign_handler()?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization, conditional-statements

Fellow coders.

If I send a SIGINT signal to a thread stuck on pthread_cond_wait(), when sign_handler() returns, will pthread_cond_wait() return as well?

If not, is there any way to make pthread_cond_wait() return?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. Why would you want to do that? It is impossible to use in a race free way anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> If I send a SIGINT signal to a thread stuck on pthread_cond_wait(), when sign_handler() returns, will pthread_cond_wait() return as well?

No.

> If not, is there any way to make pthread_cond_wait() return?

No, you're trying to use the wrong tool to solve whatever underlying problem you have.

(Technically, `pthread_cond_timedwait()` is *allowed* to return when interrupted by a signal delivery, but it does not do so, at least when using GNU glibc 2.27 on x86-64 running kernel 5.3.0.  Yes, I checked.)

> How can I fix my problem?

Let's assume that a condition variable is the best option for your use case.  (That's just a guess, though; you didn't tell us about your real problem you're trying to solve, only how your chosen solution isn't working.)

Then, the recommended solution is to use a helper thread to catch signals like SIGINT, using [sigwaitinfo()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) or sigtimedwait().  That helper thread can then set a specific `volatile sig_atomic_t you_need_to_exit` flag, and `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()` on the relevant condition variables to let them know something important happened.  Those waiting on the condition variables should obviously *first* check the helper flag; and if set, assume that that was the source for the wakeup signal.  Usually I name such flags `need_to_exit` or similar.

The key in such signal handling helper threads is that the signals need to be blocked in all threads (including the handling helper thread itself).  It is best to do this in the main thread before creating any other threads, as then the created threads inherit that same signal mask.

The siginfo_t structure contains all kinds of useful information.  Most useful is perhaps the `.si_pid` field, which tells which process (or `0` if kernel) sent the signal.  That way, if you use say `SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0` signals for internal purposes, you can ignore them unless they come from the process itself (other threads, `.si_pid == getpid()`).

Thread cancellation (deferred, at cancellation points; pthread_cond_wait() being a cancellation point) is another option.  You can use pthread_cleanup_push() to set/add functions to be run if the thread is cancelled.  This basically forcibly kills the target thread, but it can run any cleanup functions it has set up before it dies.  You can also defuse any cleanup functions using pthread_cleanup_pop() -- a parameter specifies whether the cleanup function is run and discarded, or just discarded.  But, when cancelled, the thread always dies.

---

Do use `pthread_attr_t` to limit the stack size to a sane power of two.  If you don't have any large arrays or structures on stack (local variables), then something like

```
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef  THREAD_STACK_SIZE
#define  THREAD_STACK_SIZE  (4 * PTHREAD_STACK_MIN)
#endif
```

with

```
sigset_t        mask;
pthread_attr_t  attrs;
int             err;

/* Block SIGINT in this (and all created threads) */
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
err = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
if (err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot block signals: %s.\n", strerror(err));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

/* Create stack size attribute. */
pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREAD_STACK_SIZE);

/*
 * Create threads, use &attrs for the second parameter.
*/

/* Optional cleanup - it's a good idea to be careful. */
pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);
```

should work fine, for both stack size and blocking some signals in all threads (by blocking them first in the thread that creates the other threads; they'll inherit the signal mask).

You can add any other signals to the blocked mask you like, except that `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be blocked, caught, or ignored.

The `pthread_attr_t` second parameter to `pthread_create()` is just a collection of settings (or attributes), like configuration; they are not "consumed" by the pthread_create() call.  You can use the same set of attributes any number of times.  This one contains only the desired stack size.  (It does not contain the stack itself, only the desired size.)

The default stack size is very large, typically 8 MiB, which means that a lot of virtual memory is reserved for thread stacks for no good reason, really.  Also, it severely limits the number of threads a process can create.

In many ways, having a helper thread for signal handling is easier than actual signal handlers, because only [async-signal safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) are safe to use in a signal handler; whereas in the helper thread, you can use all.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.